# Visual Studio 2010 C++ forms application creates pointers variables instead of regular variables

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am trying to redirect the console output of a process my application is launching to a textbox. I am following [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e52175ba-7879-4da4-a253-b4f3ae55637b/redirect-output-from-a-process-with-a-wcf-service?forum=wpf) example.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private: System::Void button_backup_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

                 Process^ childprocess = gcnew Process();
                 childprocess->StartInfo = gcnew ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
                 childprocess->StartInfo->UseShellExecute = false;
                 childprocess->EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                 childprocess->StartInfo->CreateNoWindow = true;
                 childprocess->ErrorDataReceived += gcnew DataReceivedEventHandler(process_DataReceived);
                 childprocess->OutputDataReceived += gcnew DataReceivedEventHandler(process_DataReceived);
                 childprocess->Start();
                 childprocess->WaitForExit();
}
```

**First Question:**
Since I have started to learn C++ Windows Forms applications a few days ago, I was never able to use code that contained the dot operator. I always had to replace everything by ->. For example, in the previous block of code, If I try:

```
Process process = new Process();
```

like it's written in the tutorial, I receive error C2750: 'System::Diagnostics::Process' : cannot use 'new' on the reference type; use 'gcnew' instead.

This also happens when I create some object using the Form GUI. Say for example a comboBox. To set the items I need to do: comboBox->Items->Add. With dots it doesn't compile and gives errors, but most tutorials I see have dots instead of ->. Why is my Visual Studio not generating code that would work with dots?

**Second Question:**
I want to complete the example I linked to. I need to implement

```
 void process_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
  {
   richTextBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action( delegate()
   {
    richTextBox.AppendText(e.Data);
   })
   );
  }
```

but it's not working at all. I have put this piece of code just after the previous block, which is itself after #pragma endregion as generated by Visual Studio C++ (this is where Visual Studio++ puts the code for events).

I notice that my Visual Studio C++ generates parameters list that look like this:

```
(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
```

Whereas in the example:

```
(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
```

Why is not the same format?

Thank you.

Comment: The example is written in C#. You are using C++/CLI. These look misleadingly similar, but they are very different, only superficially related, languages.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't C++, and those aren't pointers.  Tag changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
```

That is a language called C++/CLI (Common Language Infrastructure).  It is an adaptation of C++ which uses the CLR directly.  It's not C++.  You can create modules which can be consumed natively by any other CLR language, but the code (at minimum, the `ref` classes) is compiled to MSIL, not native machine code.

```
(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
```

That is C#.  The two signatures are semantically identical (well, except for the difference between the types of the `EventArgs` arguments), but the languages are different.